# Graph Batch API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, batch-processing, facebook-php-sdk

this is my first post at stackoverflow.

I am using the Facebook Graph Batch API to request the Feed-Updates from several users at once. 
But I really don't know how the appropriate error handling is done. Following example should demonstrate my problem:

Batch request:

```
user1 - valid access_token
user2 - invalid (password change maybe?)
user3 - valid access_otken
```

The answer from Facebook could look like this:

```
successful answer
unsuccessful answer (OAuth Exception)
successful answer
```

But reading the docs, it seems like that the ordering of the answer is **not** guaranteed. So my question is, how do I connect the answers with their specific partial requests from the batch request?

Handling the OAuth exception is quite hard when you don't get the information to which request this exception belongs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the PHP SDK, but on the Javascript SDK batching actually simulates the various calls themselves and returns an array of responses with `header` and `body` and such-like set.

You can then iterate through that looking for errors and responses.

I assume that the PHP SDK will use similar semantics.

Comment: Well, how do you know that the order for request and their responses is preserved? The documentation does not state that in a way - as already mentioned in the question. And actually this is my problem.

Comment: The docs just state the requests may be executed in an arbitrary order _on the server_. Your responses will always be in the same order, guaranteed. The whole batch concept makes no sense if not.
The execution order on the server matters when the batched requests are dependent on each other in any sense. And there's a graph semantic for expressing that too.